# Whats is JD Edwards? How is used JD Edwards?

Tags: jdedwards

i want to know detailed information about JD Edwards. How is used JD Edwards? Generally, what can I do in jd edwards? i've searched about it but cannot find wished info.

Answer (score 3):

JD Edwards is an ERP for managing a business

There's a wiki that explain it very well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JD_Edwards

The complete documentation of the product can be found on the oracle web site http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16582_01/index.htm

JDE has many modules (but not limited to)

- Manage projects
- Human resources
- Procurement
- Sales Order
- Supply management
- CRM
- Finance
- Pricing
- Transportation
- Work order

and many more

Answer (score 1):

Jdedwards is oracle ERP. Platform where it can be installed is real time platforms of customers. Osperating System it uses is windows or IBM As400. Just think that SAP is bigger business clients ( Adidas puma) and JDE is smaller and for medium business clients ( banks shops stores)  choice. Customer asks service and support for smooth transactions. Customer interface with the database is interfaced by a frontend software just call this Jde. Next jde is two types on the basis of backend database wich is used by customer, IBM Db2 and Oracle 12g. So customer saves store data in database through Jde. The above Wikipedia link can answer most answers.